# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function in case of server side rendering with react

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-router-v4

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I am facing this issue when trying to use `<Navbar/>` component outside `<Switch>` (react-router-dom) in case of react-helmet when doing server side rendering.

Comment: Its difficult to help without seeing code . Please add some code .